# Is gay sodomy considered a worse sin than straight sodomy?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, homosexuality

The top answer to this question [What does the Quran say about homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/226/17163) says:

> Homosexual acts are strictly forbidden in Islam. Although it has mainly been focused around men, women homosexuals are not that strongly discussed.  -- muslim1

And the answer to [To what extent is anal sex Haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17793/17163) quotes the Hadith:

> "Allah is not shy to tell you the truth: do not have intercourse with your wives in the anus."—Narrated by Ahmad, 5/213

(see also: [In Islam, are there limits on sex between a married couple?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1355/17163))

This motivates my question:

**Question**: Is gay sodomy considered a worse sin than straight sodomy?

I think I can safely believe that Islam has a strongly anti-gay-sodomy attitude.  On the other hand, Islam does not seem to have such a reputation for straight sodomy.

Comment: I'm not sure if one could answer this as all reports saying that straight sodomy is allowed have been falsified by scholars pretending that these statements where misunderstood.

Comment: There's e.g. ahadith on these things, and perhaps the strength of these statements could result in an imbalance between these two acts.  I'm not sure, though (hence the question).

Answer (score 1):

*The Reliance of the Traveller*, The Classic Manual of Islamic Sacred Law 'Umdat al-Salik, by Ahmad ibn Naqib al-Misri (translated by Nuh Ha Mim Keller), which describes Shafi'i fiqh, classifies these sins.

**Summary**: There's strong evidence that gay sodomy is an enormity (major sin), while the evidence is less strong for straight sodomy with one's wife.  *The Reliance* classified straight sodomy with one's wife as a "probable enormity".

#### Gay sodomy is an enormity

> p17.0 SODOMY AND LESBIANISM
>
> In more than one place in the Holy Koran,
>   Allah recounts to us the story of Lot's people, and
>   how He destroyed them for their wicked practice.
>   There is consensus among both Muslims and the
>   followers of all other religions that sodomy is an
>   enormity. It is even viler and uglier than adultery.

They cite [Qur'an 26:165-166](https://quran.com/26/165-166): *Do you approach males among the worlds And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing.*

They also cite three hadith:

1. > Kill the one who sodomizes and the one who lets it be done to him.

   This seems to be [Sunan Abi Dawud 4462](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/112) [grade: hasan sahih]
2. > May Allah curse him who does what Lot's people did.

   This is described as "Musnad Ahmad (1/317) No. 2915, This was classed as hasan by Shu’ayb al-Arna’oot in Tahqeeq al-Musnad" at [authentictauheed.com](http://www.authentictauheed.com/2012/08/338-tafseer-surah-furqan-part-8.html)
3. > Lesbianism by women is adultery between them.

   For more about this hadith, see [Did the Prophet say "lesbianism among women is zina between them"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36525/17163)

#### Straight sodomy (with one's wife) is a *probable* enormity

> SODOMIZING ONE'S WIFE
>
> p75.20 The Prophet (Allah Bless him and give
>   him peace) said,
>
> > "He who sodomizes a woman is accursed."

I did not immediately find further information about this hadith.

It is later listed as an enormity (twice) in *Ibn Hajar Haytami's List of Enormities* (within *The Reliance*):

> (258) sodomizing one's wife;
>
> (338-43) fornication; sodomy; bestiality;
>   sodomizing a woman; lesbianism between women
>   (meaning one woman doing with another that
>   which resembles what a man would do with her);
>   or for a husband to have intercourse with the body
>   of a deceased wife;